# How to hide next button from android keyboard?

Tags: android

i just want to hide next button from android keyboard which is open when focus on Edittext please help me if you are having any solution

Comment: Use imeoptions to set some actions instead of action of next

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
  android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

into your EditText.

or

In code

```
myEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```